# How to select two columns with a single WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I `select` more than one table in sql server while using a single `where` clause condition
for both tables? For example, if I had two tables named `table1`, `table2`, then:

```
select * from table1,table2 where rollno=1
```

But in the above query it gives me error -

> ambiguous column

which is logical.

Comment: just do `select * from table1, table2 where table1.rollno = 1 AND table2.rollno = 1;`

Comment: it's appropriate to select one of the answers below as correct if they helped you. NoDisplayName's answer is most similar to mine (although they used Aliases for tablename, which is not required), and M Ali used a join, which will only return results from the tables where both have the same value in column `rollno`, which may or may not be what you are after (it's up to you and your data).

Comment: If you are going to use a cross join I would recommend you be explicit and not just list tables in a comma separated list.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered so others (myself included) can already see in the question queue that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `Alias name` or use the `tablename` to avoid `ambiguous column error`  and try.

```
select * from table1 A,table2 B where A.rollno=1 AND B.rollno=1
```

Comment: Oh hey, this is the right solution, +1... By the way, this question's a trifle. Was also wondering how two users decided to upvote pre-edit, but whatever.